# NSManagedObject.setValue(value: AnyObject?, forKey key: String) causes error in Swift 2.0

Tags: swift2

I have this piece of code which was working ok in XCode6 (Swift 1.2) but not with the Swift 2:

```
class func findOrCreate<T: NSManagedObject>(type: T.Type, attribute: String, value: AnyObject?) -> T {
    if let object = T.MR_findFirstByAttribute(attribute, withValue: value) as? T {
        return object
    } else {
        let object = T.MR_createEntity() as! T
        if let value:AnyObject = value {
            object.setValue(value, forKey: attribute)
        }
        return object
    }
}
```

Error shows on the line containing *object.setValue* with the message:

**Ambiguous use of 'setValue(_:forKey:)'**

I think it does not recognise object to be of NSManagedObject type but I'm not 100% sure, any clue why this happens much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

I've posted same question on Apple Forum and got an answer with a workaround for this problem:

```
      let object = T.MR_createEntity() as! NSManagedObject
      if let value:AnyObject = value {   
           object.setValue(value, forKey: attribute)   
      }   
      return object as! T
```

This works as expected. I've submitted a bug report to Apple as well.

Comment: good work, I ran into this same issue, and your comment helped me out! do update here on the resolution of the Bug from Apple. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

One more possible solution is this:

```
(object as NSManagedObject).setValue(value, forKey: attribute)
```

Comment: thx! today I also ran into the same issue. This bug still exists with Xcode 7.3.1.